# Browser Incompability - wrong rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, jqplot

I'm using jqplot. My chart is mentioned to looks like in the first image. 
It looks good in firefox. But in chrome(i.e. v30) it looks like in the second image. 
It doesn't work at all in Safari.

Edit: I guess the problem is in date format.
I declare for example `min: '01.10.2013',` `max: '22.10.2013'`
but chrome displays min `10.01.2013` max `22.10.2013.` This rule is valid for the whole series.
How can I change this behavior and tell chrome, that I use `dd.mm.yyyy` date format?

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<div id="chart2" style="height:250px; width:596px;"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){


  var line1 = [['01.10.2013',0],['02.10.2013',-0.42437431991294],['03.10.2013',-1.9912948857454],['04.10.2013',-1.512513601741],['07.10.2013',-2.3177366702938],['08.10.2013',-2.6115342763874],['09.10.2013',-3.4711643090316],['10.10.2013',-1.316648531012],['11.10.2013',-0.54406964091403],['14.10.2013',-0.71817192600653],['15.10.2013',-1.7627856365615],['16.10.2013',-1.8824809575626],['17.10.2013',-2.9815016322089],['18.10.2013',-1.0663764961915],['21.10.2013',-1.512513601741]];   
  var line2 = [['01.10.2013',0],['02.10.2013',-0.42437431991294],['03.10.2013',-1.9912948857454],['04.10.2013',-1.512513601741],['07.10.2013',-2.3177366702938],['08.10.2013',-2.6115342763874],['09.10.2013',-3.4711643090316],['10.10.2013',-1.316648531012],['11.10.2013',-0.54406964091403],['14.10.2013',-0.71817192600653],['15.10.2013',-1.7627856365615],['16.10.2013',-1.8824809575626],['17.10.2013',-2.9815016322089],['18.10.2013',-1.0663764961915],['21.10.2013',-1.512513601741]];
  var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line2,line1], {


    seriesDefaults: { lineWidth: 0.8, showMarker:false,  showMarker:false },




    grid: {background:'#fdfdfd', borderWidth: 0.4 },
        series: [            
        {label: 'incl. Dividende'},
      {label: 'excl. Dividende'}
        ],
        seriesColors: [ "#009933", "#003399"],
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%d.%m.%Y'
            },
        min: '01.10.2013',
        max: '22.10.2013'
     }
        }
    });
  mytitle = $('<div class="my-jqplot-title" style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif ;color:#DDDDDD; font-size:27px;position:absolute;text-align:center;top: 101px;width:100%; ">CHART</div>').insertBefore('.jqplot-series-canvas');//('.jqplot-grid-canvas');


});
```

Comment: Could you post the code so we can try and replicate?

Comment: Also please mention the browser version that you are using to test.

Comment: @Sébastien: should I also post line2 and line1?

Comment: Please post all relevant HTML and JavaScript

Comment: I guess the problem is in date format. I declare for example min: '01.10.2013', max: '22.10.2013' but chrome displays min 10.01.2013 max 22.10.2013.

Comment: i would convert the date time to a standard dateTime object using `Date()` object and then use those values in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define min and max values in a correct format :

```
axes: {
 xaxis: {
  renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
  tickOptions: { formatString: '%d.%m.%Y' },
  min: '2013-10-01',
  max: '2013-10-22'
 }
}
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/qRnmd/)